# Issues in dynamically adding Description list in HTML using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a DL(description list) with some values in respective DTs and DDs. here i used toggle function to see and hide DD. i have an add button . on clicking of it , two textboxes open to fill up a data. after filling up a data, when i click on save , new DT and DD gets added to my DL. but toggle function is not working for newly added DT and DD. Please help me here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#newpromos").hide();
 $("#promos dd").hide();
 
  $("#promosave").click(function(){
      
      var title=$("#promotitle").val();
      var desc=$("#promodetails").val();
      
      if(title.length && desc.length){
              $('<dt />', {html: title}).appendTo('#promos');
              $('<dd />', {html: desc}).appendTo('#promos');
          }
      $("#promos dd").hide();
      
     });
 
    $("#promos dt").click(function () {
        $(this).next("#promos dd").slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    });
 
    $("#addpromos").click(function(){
     $("#newpromos").show();
    });
 
   
});
```

```css
#promos dt, #promos dd { padding: 0 0 0 50px }
#promos dt { font-size:1.5em; color: #9d9d9d; cursor: pointer; height: 37px; line-height: 37px; margin: 0 0 15px 25px}
#promos dd { font-size: 1em; margin: 0 0 20px 25px}
#promos dt { background: url(http://www.designonslaught.com/files/2012/06/expand-icon.png) no-repeat left}
#promos .expanded { background: url("http://www.designonslaught.com/files/2012/06/expanded-icon.png") no-repeat left}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Promo">
    <div>
        <dl id="promos">
            <dt>title1</dt>
            <dd>
                <p>
                    description1
                </p>
            </dd>
            <dt>title2</dt>
            <dd>
                <p>description2</p>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div id="newpromos">
        <input type="text" id="promotitle">
        <br>
        <textarea id="promodetails"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="promosave">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Promotions" id="addpromos">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event as "delegate event":

```
$(document).on("click", "#promos dt",function () {
    $(this).next("#promos dd").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
});
```